# как вывести всплывающее модальное окно после отправки данных на почту?

Tags: javascript, php, css

помогите пожалуйста разобраться в коде. суть в том чтобы после заполнении формы вышло модальное окно с благодарностью.
если в PHP есть div.status - после отправки формы на почту - показывается окно но без css стилей.
а если убрать  div.status с корня PHP и поместить в index.html - после отправки данных показывается пустая страница. (перезагружая страницу форма отправляется повторно).
как добиться успеха чтоб модальное окно высвечивалось как нужно со стилями?
Благодарю за внимание.

P.S.: Не судите строго новичка ;)
прилагаю сайт и окно как должно выглядеть.

http://kate-sites.com/

[image: как должно выглядеть окно]

index.html

```
    <section class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay__modal" id="consultation">
            <div class="overlay__close"> &times; </div>
            <div class="overlay__header"> Просто заполните форму заявки</div>
            <div class="overlay__subheader">и мы перезвоним вам в течении 10 минут</div>
            <form class="feed-forms feed-forms_overlay " action="sender.php" method="post">
                <input name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" type="text" >
                <input name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон"  >
                <input name="email" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" type="email" >
                <button class="button_main">заказать кОНСУЛЬТАЦИЮ</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="status overlay__modal overlay__modal_thanks " id="thanks">
            <div class="overlay__close"> &times; </div>
            <div class="overlay__header">Спасибо за вашу заявку!</div>
            <div class="overlay__subheader">Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время!</div>
        </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    $to = "kate.pidoni@gmail.com"; 
    $date = date ("d.m.Y"); 
    $time = date ("h:i");
    $from = $email;
    $subject = "Заявка c сайта";

    
    $msg="
    Имя: $name /n
    Фамилия: $surname /n
    Телефон: $phone /n
    Почта: $email /n
    Текст: $text";  
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $to ");

?>

        <div class="status overlay__modal overlay__modal_thanks " id="thanks">
            <div class="overlay__close"> &times; </div>
            <div class="overlay__header">Спасибо за вашу заявку!</div>
            <div class="overlay__subheader">Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время!</div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
      jQuery('.button_main').click( function() {
        var form = jQuery(this).closest('form');
        
        if ( form.valid() ) {
          var actUrl = form.attr('action');
  
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: actUrl,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                      $('#thanks').modal('show'); // для бутстрапа
            },
            error:   function() {
                 form.find('.status').html('серверная ошибка');
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

SCSS

```
.overlay  {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
    &__modal {
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 382px;
        min-height: 402px;
        background: #F2F2F2;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        &_thanks {
            min-height: 143px;
            .overlay__subheader {
                width: 243px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
    
        }
    }
    .error {
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    label.error {
        border: none;
    }
    &__close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 400px;
        font-size: 41px;
        line-height: 15px;
        color: $main-color;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    &__header {
        margin-top: 32px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 19px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    &__subheader {
        margin-bottom: 26px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
    }  
}
#consultation , #order , #thanks {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо в файл, где находятся все стили, добавить стили для модального окна, к ним относятся: `status overlay__modal overlay__modal_thanks` и все классы ниже.

Comment: Выше добавила SCSS код так же. все ровно не работают стили с всплывающим окном.

Comment: SCSS - это препроцесор. Он должен быть сгенерирован в CSS, после чего подключен к общему файлу. Для преобразования можете воспользоваться онлайн генераторами. https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/

Comment: все это сделано ;) но всеровно проблема осталась..

Comment: значит у вас как-то не так назначены стили, по тому и не применились. Скорее всего напутали с каскадностью. Перепроверте совпадение ваших названий классов с тем что вы задаете в CSS